# Is a good practice to do several callbacks to get data from DB in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, entity-framework-4, silverlight-4.0, callback

I'm using SL 5.0 and EntityFramework. I need to get data from two entities, but I don't like the way which I'm doing.. through callbacks.

```
var context = ...
context.Load(context.GetTestTemplatesSummaryQuery("OPA-3DKCL2")).Completed += (s, e) =>
    {
        var result = context.GetTestTemplatesSummary_Results;
        var result2 = ...

        context.Load(context.GetTestTemplatesSummaryQuery(result)).Completed += (s2, e2) =>
        {
             ... 
        };
    };
```

I'm looking for an elegant way to do this.

Comment: http://10rem.net/blog/2012/05/22/using-async-and-await-in-silverlight-5-and-net-4-in-visual-studio-11-with-the-async-targeting-pack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is completely right for .Net versions 1.0 to 4.0.  This is how asyncronous programming works in the world of .Net.

With .Net 4.5 there is a new async/await mechansim for asynchronous programming which looks like this:

```
public async Data GetData()
{
    return await _myService.GetDataAsync();
}
```

When you compile the code it gets broken down into a series of asynchronous methods, but the code the developer writes is significantly simplified.

As mentioned above, if you have VS 2012 (VS 11) then you can download a pack that allows you to use await async with Silverlight 5.  If you're not using VS 2012 then what you're doing currently is exactly right.